# Is it possible to put a Ricci-flat metric on the $n$-sphere for $ n>4$?

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, riemannian-geometry, flatness

I'm looking for references which discuss the possibility of putting a Ricci-flat metric on the $n$-sphere for $n > 4$.

Thank you for any kind of help.

Comment: This is an open problem. See [this](http://mathoverflow.net/q/68094/21564) MathOverflow question.

Comment: ok, thank you but only i want references not solutions

Comment: References to what exactly? The answer to the question is not known one way or the other.

Comment: reference about this problem since it open .

Comment: Following the Mathflow questions, it seems they all cite the book A panoramic view of Riemannian geometry (May be a good way to start)

Comment: ok, thank you for those info

Comment: That you ask this question is very odd, judging from the huge level gap between it and the others you asked on the site. How comes?